# Sorting a Basic Tree in SWT/Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, sorting, tree, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am building an Eclipse RCP application and require some trees to be sorted Alphabetically. Is there a way to Sort the contents of a Tree in SWT? I **do not** have columns in the Tree; this is just a plain old tree like you can find in the Eclipse Package Explorer. In fact; I would love it if I could do the exact same thing that is in the Package Explorer (alphabetic sorting.)

I have tried the following:

```
Arrays.sort(treeItem.getItems());
```

But `TreeItem` doesn't implement `Comparable<T>` so it won't work.

Comment: Where's your code that you tried?

Comment: Yes there are ways to sort trees, this is much easier if you are using TreeViewer.

Comment: @greg-449 that is the JFace TreeViewer correct? How would I go about doing it with that?

Comment: TreeViewer has a `setComparator` method where you specify a class extending ViewerComparator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using Tree directly, you can take a look to the chapter "Sorting trees": http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/expeditor-swt/

I recommend to use TreeViewer and look at "Viewer Sorter" chapter: https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TreeViewer/TreeViewerArticle.htm

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can't sort the tree, but you can add new items in a sorted fashion, which in effect will sort the tree:

```
private TreeItem insertItemSorted( TreeItem parentItem, KeyInfo keyInfo )
{
    TreeMap<String, Integer> sorted = new TreeMap<>();
    TreeItem newItem = null;
    TreeItem[] siblings;
    KeyInfo info;
    int index;

    if (parentItem == null || parentItem.getParent() == null)
        siblings = ivKeyTree.getItems();
    else
        siblings = parentItem.getItems();

    index = 0;

    for (TreeItem item : siblings)
    {
        info = (KeyInfo) item.getData();

        sorted.put( info.getSortKey(), new Integer( index++ ) );
    }

    sorted.put( keyInfo.getSortKey(), new Integer( -1 ) );

    index = 0;

    for (Integer number : sorted.values().toArray( new Integer[sorted.size()] ))
    {
        if (number.intValue() == -1)
        {
            if (parentItem == null || parentItem.getParent() == null)
                newItem = new TreeItem( ivKeyTree, Editor.TREE_KEY_STYLE, index );
            else
                newItem = new TreeItem( parentItem, Editor.TREE_KEY_STYLE, index );

            break;
        }

        index++;
    }

    if (newItem == null)
    {
        if (parentItem == null || parentItem.getParent() == null)
            newItem = new TreeItem( ivKeyTree, Editor.TREE_KEY_STYLE );
        else
            newItem = new TreeItem( parentItem, Editor.TREE_KEY_STYLE );
    }

    return newItem;
}
```

You can substitute the Interface keyInfo for a String. I'm using the interface because I am sorting values below expandable levels. The sort key starts with -a- for the levels, and -b- for the values. So the value name "Trend" will have a sort key of "-b-trend", and so on.

+Top
+-Items
+-More Items
----Value
--Basic Value